# Will Linq query code in C# UWP project work slower or faster depending on order of its' parts?

Tags: c#, performance, linq, sqlite, uwp

I have this general question to know whether SQLite db query using Linq may be faster or slower depending on order of parts of it.

Let's say I have a DB table with multiple user data.

If I write something like this:

```
var Query = DB_List.Where(TableName => TableName.UserId == UserId &&
                                       TableName.SomeValue == SomeValue);
```

Will it be faster than:

```
var Query = DB_List.Where(TableName => TableName.SomeValue == SomeValue &&
                                       TableName.UserId == UserId);
```

considering that there may be thousands of userId's??

Personally I think it may be better to first identify current UserId records and then check them for value we look for, but maybe it does not make a difference.

Comment: I think it depends on if the table has an index matching your query or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is rather about SQLite itself than about UWP. The only thing UWP does in this case is translate the LINQ query into a SQL query that goes to the database. In this case it will be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE SomeValue == @someValue AND UserId = @userId
```

Now, the order in which the `WHERE` clause conditions are listed **does not matter**. Before executing the query, SQLite will prepare an **execution plan** that will attempt to choose the most performant order of evaluation. Here it will first and foremost prioritize **indexed columns** - so if you want to improve performance, this is where should start.

Creating an index in SQLite is similar to any other database:

```
CREATE INDEX idxUserId ON MyTable (UserId);
```

You can even include multiple columns:

```
CREATE INDEX idxUserIdSomeValue ON MyTable (UserId, SomeValue);
```

When you setup an index, the DB will essentially maintain a sorted ordering of the rows in the table to allow for blazingly fast binary search, which will aid your scenario perfectly. Also note, that primary column of all tables is automatically indexed.

For more information on SQLite Indices, see [this great article by Jason Feinstein](https://medium.com/@JasonWyatt/squeezing-performance-from-sqlite-indexes-indexes-c4e175f3c346).

Comment: I love your answer and the article link!